# Overload Resolution with g++

Tags: c++, g++

I am working on implementing a serialization class, `Serializable`. This class has the following method signatures:

```
void serializeMember(Buffer& sb, const Serializable*& member) const;
void serializeMember(Buffer& sb, const int& member) const;
template<typename T>
  void deserializeMember(Buffer& sb, T*& member);
```

I have a derived class `Baz` and another derived class `Bar`. `Bar` has a member variable `Baz* baz;`. `Bar` has the following methods:

```
void deserialize(Buffer& buffer) {
  deserializeMember(buffer, baz);
}
void serialize(Buffer& buffer) const {
  serializeMember(buffer, baz);
}
```

When I execute my code, the call to serialize resolves to the `serializeMember` overload with `int` as the second parameter. Same as if I make that a template function, similar to `deserializeMember`. The call to `deseralizeMember` resolves correctly.

Why doesn't my `Serializable` pointer resolve to the correct overloaded method?

Comment: Just a check: can you comment out the method that takes an `int` as the second parameter and see what happens?

Comment: `serializeMember` takes a non-const reference to `const Serializable*`, not a const reference to `Serializable*` as you probably intended.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you think "the correct overloaded method" should be. By your own admission, it's _not_ that in reality, so you have to actually tell us what you wanted instead...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the "correct overloaded method" is the most specific match available. Since Baz inherits from Serializable, Serializable*& is "correct".

Comment: @molbdnilo you're correct, thanks! Here is the right signature: `void serializeMember(Buffer& sb, const Serializable* const& member) const;`

Comment: @Jake I believe that is a non-const reference to `const Serializable* const` (equivalent to `Serializable const * const &`). Why can't you use just `const Serializable*`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm assuming because a const pointer is different from a const reference. With `const Serializable*` the object being pointed to is const. With `const Serializable*& const` both the object being pointed to and the referenced pointer itself are const. Since the `serializeMember` method is a const method of `Bar`, its pointed `Baz` object and its `Baz` pointer need to be const in this context as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature is:

```
void serializeMember(Buffer& sb, const Serializable* const& member) const;
```

Since `serializeMember` is a const method of `Bar`, and `baz` is a pointer beloning to `Bar`, we need to either pass the const pointer by value or pass the const pointer as a const reference. Hence, `const Serializable* const&`.